# Função imprimir com erro

Tags: c++, array, c++11, c++14

Fiz um programa que calcula os números de Fibonacci em X e Y usando Z como auxiliar.

Quando eu passo o vetor da função de Fibonacci para a função `imprime`, ela não imprime. Fiz um teste colocando um `cout` dentro do `for` do cálculo e constatei que o erro é justamente na função `imprime`, tendo em vista que o `cout` no cálculo faz tudo exatamente como tinha que fazer. Suspeito que o problema seja exatamente no `for` de `imprime`.

Creio que essa informação irá ajudar: minha função `imprime` gera um erro que eu não sei resolver:

> C4018 '<': Unsigned mismatch

Programa.h:

```
#pragma once
#ifndef __MEU_H_INCLUDED__
#define __MEU_H_INCLUDED__

#include <stdlib.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
#include <string>
#include <vector>



void imprime(std::vector<int>& v);
void fibonacci(int x, int y, std::vector<int> fi, int numeroElementos);

#endif
```

cpp de implementação:

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include "meu.h"


using std::cout;
using std::endl;


void imprime(std::vector<int>& v)
{

    for(int x = 0; x < v.size(); x++)
        cout << v[x];
}

void fibonacci(int x, int y, std::vector<int> fi, int numeroElementos)
{

    int z = 0;

    for (int b = 0; b <= numeroElementos; b++)
    {
        z = x + y;
        fi.push_back(z);
        x = y;
        y = z;      
    }           
}
```

Main.cpp :

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include "meu.h"

int main()
{
    int valor1 = 0;
    int valor2 = 0;
    int NumeroElementos = 0;
    std::vector<int> numeros;

     while (std::cin >> valor1 >> valor2 >> NumeroElementos) {
         fibonacci(valor1, valor2, numeros, NumeroElementos);
         imprime(numeros);
    }





    system("pause");

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Você precisaria passar o vetor sempre por referência, como fez corretamente na função `imprime()`. Aí parece que o erro é nela, mas na verdade ele ocorreu antes e o vetor não é corretamente preenchido como se espera. Eu simplificaria o código assim:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
using namespace std;

void imprime(vector<int>& v) {
    for(int x = 0; x < v.size(); x++) cout << v[x] << " ";
}

void fibonacci(int x, int y, vector<int>& fi) {
    int z = 0;
    for (int b = 0; b < fi.size(); b++) {
        z = x + y;
        fi[b] = z;
        x = y;
        y = z;      
    }           
}

int main() {
    int valor1, valor2, numeroElementos;
    while (cin >> valor1 >> valor2 >> numeroElementos) {
        vector<int> numeros(numeroElementos);
        fibonacci(valor1, valor2, numeros);
        imprime(numeros);
    }
}
```

Veja [funcionando no **ideone**](https://ideone.com/R8l4Rd). E [no **repl.it**](https://repl.it/join/rndenunn-maniero). Também [coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/CPP/Algorithm/PrintFibonacci.cpp).

Answer (score 3):

Troque isso:

```
void fibonacci(int x, int y, std::vector<int> fi, int numeroElementos);
```

por isso:

```
void fibonacci(int x, int y, std::vector<int>& fi, int numeroElementos);
```

E faça a mesma mudança na definição da função. Além disso, declare o vetor `numeros` dentro do `while`, fica assim:

```
while (std::cin >> valor1 >> valor2 >> NumeroElementos) {
    std::vector<int> numeros;
    fibonacci(valor1, valor2, numeros, NumeroElementos);
    imprime(numeros);
}
```